# Jquery make closest select field required true

Tags: jquery

In my Rails application, I have checkbox which hides and shows `select field` when checkbox is clicked. When checkbox is unchecked then `select field` is visible to user. What I want to achieve is when checkbox is unchecked (when select is visible) to user, make `select` field required true.

Below is part of my html

```
 <div class='row finished'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :finished, 'Finished Month' %>
        <%= f.select :finish_month, WorkExperiencesHelper.months, { prompt: '-- Select --' }, class: 'form-control finished-month' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :finished, 'Finished Year' %>
        <%= f.select :finish_year, WorkExperiencesHelper.years, { prompt: '-- Select --' }, class: 'form-control finished-year' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :still_in_role %>
        <%= f.check_box :still_in_role, class: 'still-in-role' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Below is my Jquery code

```
    $('.still-in-role').change(function(){
      if(this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('.row').prev('.finished').hide();
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.row').prev('.finished').show();
      }
    })
```

I have tried below code but it's not working:

```
$(this).closest('.row').prev('.finished-year').attr('required', true);
```

Below code works but it will make all `select field` required which I don't what because there are 4 select fields in the page.

```
$("select").attr("required", true);
```

So how can I make `select field` required when checkbox is unchecked. I only want to make closest `select field` from checkbox to have `required true`.

Comment: Hi, you can try `$(this).closest('.finished').find('.finished-year').attr('required', true);`

Comment: @Swati I tried this, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show your html generated of your code ?

Comment: @Swati I tried to put the generated html of code, but its too messy to copy/paste. Thanks for your help anyway.